iOS 18 ZStack prevent touch event propagation
The following code works to any iOS version excepted iOS 18, invisible view (UIViewRepresentable) are added above specific view to create clickable link.
The following issue is only on iOS 18  -> The top view of the ZStack is catching all the touch event (touchBegan) while they're side by side but on top of each other ?
Any clue how I could make the ZStack's subviews still receive the touch event on iOS 18 instead of the last/top one of the stack ?
@ViewBuilder
private var pressabkeViews: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .top) {
         ForEach(Array(positions.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { index, link in
           pressableView(link: link, index: index)
      }
   }
}

